# openssl cleanup handlers

Tags: c, openssl

I have written an openssl program, and now I want to know, if the openssl library calls its own cleanup functions, or if I have to call myself the cleanup functions like SSL_CTX_free and SSL_free?

Comment: Also see [How to properly uninitialize OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29845527). I don't want to close this question as a duplicate since this question predates the other question. But the other question was answered more completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly call the cleanup functions. I recommend using Valgrind in order to track memory leaks in your program.

Comment: Ok so when I use `void exit(int status);` in my program, the SSL_CTX and all the SSL objects are not freed? Does calling SSL_CTX_free is enough, or do I have to call SSL_free for all SSL objects too?