# Detected mysql C API has memory leak when only init and close.How to avoid it?

Tags: c++, mysql, memory-leaks

When I test the mysql C API，the valgrind had detected memory leak.

- mysql version: 8.0.1
- OS version:CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804(Linux version
    3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64)

The test code is simple:

```
#include "mysql/mysql.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MYSQL* handle = mysql_init(nullptr);
    mysql_close(handle);
    mysql_library_end();
    return 0;
}
```

The valgrind command is:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --log-file=./memleak.log ./test.out
```

The valgrind log is:

```
==23069== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23069== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23069== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23069== Command: ./KCTestSuite.out
==23069== Parent PID: 23067
==23069== 
==23069== 
==23069== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23069==     in use at exit: 64 bytes in 2 blocks
==23069==   total heap usage: 3,787 allocs, 3,785 frees, 176,206 bytes allocated
==23069== 
==23069== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==23069==    at 0x4C29BC3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==23069==    by 0x6ED33B7: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x6F895CE: sk_new (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x6C3D619: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x6C3F898: SSL_COMP_get_compression_methods (in /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x6C457C8: SSL_library_init (in /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x550689B: ssl_start() (viosslfactories.cc:416)
==23069==    by 0x54AAE84: mysql_server_init (libmysql.cc:136)
==23069==    by 0x54B2AA4: mysql_init (client.cc:2387)
==23069==    by 0x411E78: main (main.cpp:15)
==23069== 
==23069== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
==23069==    at 0x4C29BC3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==23069==    by 0x6ED33B7: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x6F895EC: sk_new (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x6C3D619: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x6C3F898: SSL_COMP_get_compression_methods (in /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x6C457C8: SSL_library_init (in /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k)
==23069==    by 0x550689B: ssl_start() (viosslfactories.cc:416)
==23069==    by 0x54AAE84: mysql_server_init (libmysql.cc:136)
==23069==    by 0x54B2AA4: mysql_init (client.cc:2387)
==23069==    by 0x411E78: main (main.cpp:15)
==23069== 
==23069== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23069==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23069==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23069==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23069==    still reachable: 64 bytes in 2 blocks
==23069==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23069== 
==23069== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23069== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The leak maybe came from ssl,but I'm not sure.How can I avoid it?

In any case ,Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eh, it's not unusual for openssl to have issues that valgrind reports on. Not much you can do about it besides upgrading to the latest version and hoping it was fixed. Plus those aren't even memory leaks, so there's no actual issue.

Comment: Pretty sure that SSL doesn't *leak* memory other than stays initialized.

Comment: Possible a leak from [SSL_COMP_get_compression_methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845527/how-to-properly-uninitialize-openssl)

Comment: Thank you! I'll update the version and see if there are any such problems.