# Openssl RSA_new() and memory leaks detection

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, openssl

I don't know why I get memory leak in first test case (for sure it is false positive) but in the identical second test there is no leak detected.

I suspect that openssl frees memory later, not when RSA_free is invoked, at least with rsa structure.

```
TEST(TestCaseName, test1) {
    _CrtMemState state1;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state1);

    auto rsa=RSA_new();

    RSA_free(rsa);

    _CrtMemState state2;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state2);
    _CrtMemState state3;
    if (_CrtMemDifference(&state3, &state1, &state2))//memory leak detected
        _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&state3);
}

TEST(TestCaseName, test2) {
    _CrtMemState state1;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state1);

    auto rsa = RSA_new();

    RSA_free(rsa);

    _CrtMemState state2;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state2);
    _CrtMemState state3;
    if (_CrtMemDifference(&state3, &state1, &state2))//ok no leak
        _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&state3);
}
```

the output of _CrtMemDumpStatistics from the first test is below:

```
0 bytes in 0 Free Blocks.
48 bytes in 2 Normal Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 CRT Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Ignore Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Client Blocks.
Largest number used: 0 bytes.
Total allocations: 168 bytes.
```

there is no output from the second test.
Does any one know why memory leak is detected in first test but every thing is ok in the second test?

Comment: If the two tests are *identical* then the only plausible difference is their invocation contexts, of which you've provided none. Did you try adding 3rd, and 4th identical cases, just to see if a pattern emerges?

Comment: yes, I have added 2 more tests, no leaks. Leak is only in the first test

Comment: What does `_CrtMemDumpStatistics` actually report? (Please add it to your question).

Comment: ok, the report is added

Comment: Why do you say it's a leak? Do you have some reason to think the memory isn't still reachable? If you run the code twice, do you see 4 blocks or still 2? If still 2, then it's not a leak since those same blocks were re-used.

Comment: When you call a openssl function the first time, it runs parts of it's startup code.  This startup code is allocating memory.  This is the memory you are seeing leaking.  It's also the reason why it only the first test that shows this memory leak.  If you want to cleanup, you need to call the cleanup methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845527/how-to-properly-uninitialize-openssl

Comment: You could try calling _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` after you have freed everything.  This reports the file and line number of each allocated block in debug builds.

Comment: @ShanePowell that's it. openssl allocates memory on startup and that's why i see difference betwean snapshots in the first test